# reference request: Borel sigma-algebra of a subspace is the trace sigma-algebra

Tags: reference-request, borel-sets

Let $\tau$ be the standard metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  For $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, let $$\tau_E=E\cap\tau:=\{E\cap U:U\in\tau\}$$
denote the subspace topology on $E$.  We write $\sigma(\tau)$ and $\sigma(\tau_E)$ for the respective Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $\tau$ and $\tau_E$.

According to [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Borel_Sigma-Algebra_of_Subset_is_Trace_Sigma-Algebra), we have the identity
$$\sigma(\tau_E)=E\cap\sigma(\tau):=\{E\cap B:B\in\sigma(\tau)\}.$$

**My question is this:**  Can we find a more authoritative reference for the above identity than proofwiki?

I need to reference this fact in a paper I'm about to submit, and I'm pretty sure proofwiki won't go over very well, lol!

Comment: Anyone is most welcome to correct me if they think I'm wrong here, but I wouldn't have thought that a fact as trivial as this would need a reference or citation. (Well, maybe  it would in an undergraduate project or the like, but not an academic journal paper, I would think.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proofwiki itself cites "2005: René L. Schilling: Measures, Integrals and Martingales §3: Problem 10 (ii)":

> [image]

while not the same notation and not a full solution as in Proofwiki, it is indeed this result.